# How to read an iterable page by page?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I've tried a bunch of things to be able to read items page by page without loading each page in a list and returning that, which could take too much memory on big pages. I'd like to avoid getting a big list of items just to have to scan the list again to do the post-processing of each item.

So either I get generators that will keep returning empty data and fill the `pages` list with an infinite number of empty lists (when using `page_from_iterable2`), or I just get the first page (like in `page_from_iterable1`.

Any hint on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
from typing import Iterable, Iterator


def read_paginated_items(
    it: Iterator,
    page_size: int,
) -> Iterable:
    for _ in range(page_size):
        try:
            yield next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            return


def page_from_iterable1(
    iterable: Iterable,
    page_size: int,
) -> Iterable:
    it = iter(iterable)
    page_items_generator = read_paginated_items(it, page_size)
    yield page_items_generator


def page_from_iterable2(
    iterable: Iterable,
    page_size: int,
) -> Iterable:
    it = iter(iterable)
    while page_items_generator := read_paginated_items(it, page_size):
        yield page_items_generator
    

def test_read_by_page():
    pages = []
    for page in page_from_iterable1([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2):
        page_items = [item for item in page]
        pages.append(page_items)

    assert pages == [[1, 2], [2, 3], [5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's help, here's what I came up:

```
from typing import Iterator

import pytest


class PageItems:
    def __init__(
        self,
        iterator: Iterator,
        page_size: int,
    ):
        self.items_generator = self._create_items_generator(iterator, page_size)

    @staticmethod
    def _create_items_generator(
        iterator: Iterator,
        page_size: int,
    ):
        for _ in range(page_size):
            try:
                yield next(iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                return

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.items_generator)


def test_read_one_page():
    iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    page_items = PageItems(iter(iterable), 3)
    assert next(page_items) == 1
    assert next(page_items) == 2
    assert next(page_items) == 3

    with pytest.raises(StopIteration):
        next(page_items)


def test_read_pages():
    iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pages = []
    iterator = iter(iterable)

    while page_items := list(PageItems(iterator, 2)):
        pages.append(page_items)

    assert pages == [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]

def test_read_pages_modified_items():
    iterable = [(1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "C"), (4, "D"), (5, "E")]
    pages = []
    iterator = iter(iterable)

    while page_items := [item[0] for item in PageItems(iterator, 2)]:
        pages.append(page_items)

    assert pages == [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

I won't be able to use a for loop over `PageItems`, as it will always spit empty pages in the end, but with a `while` I can check for emptyness without having to resort to an ugly `if/break` block. This also allows me to either call `list(PageItems(iterator, 2))` if I just need the items without modifications, or `[item[0] for item in PageItems(iterator, 2)]` it for exemple the items returned are tuples and I just want the first element.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to maintain state within your generator.

That sounds like a job for an `iterable` class.

```
from typing import Iterable, Iterator

class Page:
    def __init__(self, it: Iterator, page_size: int):
        self.it = it
        self.page_size = page_size
        self.done = False
        self.item = 0
    
    def __iter__(self):
        self.item = 0
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        while self.item < self.page_size:
            try:
                self.item += 1
                return next(self.it)
            except StopIteration:
                # at this point the entirety of the original
                # iterator is consumed
                # self.done is our way of telling the generator
                # to stop yielding the instance of Page
                self.done = True
                raise
        # here we have reached the end of the page so we just reset the
        # item count in __iter__. The entry point on each iteration.
        raise StopIteration


def page_from_iterable(
    iterable: Iterable,
    page_size: int,
) -> Iterable:
    it = iter(iterable)
    page = Page(it, page_size)
    while not page.done:
        yield page
    

def test_read_by_page():
    pages = []
    for page in page_from_iterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2):
        page_items = [item for item in page]
        pages.append(page_items)

    print(pages)

test_read_by_page()
```

The generator works by `yield`ing the same iterator for each page. Since it continues `yield`ing the same instance of `Page` the state of the original iterator (`self.it`) is maintained.

Typically in an `__iter__` method, the state would be reset. but since we wish to continue iterating from that iterable, you only need to reset the item count back to `0`.

Comment: Not every iterable does, or can, provide a usable `__length_hint__`. That's why it's called a *hint*.

Comment: True. My preference would lean towards implementing the iterator class anyways. I added the `__length_hint__` portion after the fact because I felt like there should be a solution involving just generators. But for dynamically generated content like pages, I think I can assume it will not be accurate. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

A simplification can be done if you are willing to test for a generated pagination with 0 elements:

```py
from typing import Iterable, Iterator
import itertools

def paginate(
    it: Iterator,
    page_size: int,
) -> Iterable:
    try:
        for _ in range(page_size):
            yield it.__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        pass

def page_from_iterable(
    iterable: Iterable,
    page_size: int,
) -> Iterable:
    it = iterable.__iter__()
    while True:
        yield paginate(it, page_size)

def test_read_by_page():
    pages = []
    for page in page_from_iterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2):
        page = list(page)
        if not page:
            break
        pages.append(page)
    print(pages)

test_read_by_page()
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't like the idea of the `if not page: break`, but this can be removed by using a `while` construct.

Comment: And how would that `while` work? `page` is a generator expression and cannot be directly checked for 0 length. The only way to know whether it would generate an empty list is to either convert it into a list and check it as I do above or if your plan is to actually just iterate these generators, which I assume is really the point of generating generators to begin with because you are concerned that the list would take up too much memory, break out of the loop when you detect that you have an empty generator.

Comment: Sure, at some point I need to generate a list from the items. I just don't want the list be directly provided to me so I get a chance to modify the items. My use case for example is when each item is a tuple from which I want just the first element. See my answer to see what I mean. The while won't test the generator, but the items once I got a chance to modify them.

Answer (score 1):

```
def page_from_iterable2(
    iterable: Iterable,
    page_size: int,
) -> Iterable:
    it = iter(iterable)
    while page_items_generator := read_paginated_items(it, page_size):
        yield page_items_generator
```

The problem here is simply that the `page_items_generator` is... a generator, not the generated items. Each time through the loop, you create a new generator object; the `while` condition passes (because generator objects are truthy); you yield that object, and nothing is actually read from the nested generator.

You need to collect the results explicitly:

```
def pages_from_iterable(
    iterable: Iterable,
    page_size: int,
) -> Iterable:
    it = iter(iterable)
    while page := list(read_paginated_items(it, page_size)):
        yield page
```

Now, each time through the loop, the created generator is used to read up to `page_size` items, creating a list of items. When the source items are exhausted, you possibly get a list with fewer than `page_size` items, and then an empty list (in both cases due to the handling of `StopIteration`. Since the empty list is falsey, the `while` loop breaks and doesn't yield that list.

This means that we *don't* need to collect the per-page results externally:

```
def test_read_by_page():
    for page in pages_from_iterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2):
        print(page)
```

Perhaps you wished to defer the collection of page results to outside the generator. Unfortunately, this will simply not work: generators are truthy regardless of what they would generate, and *in the general case* the only way to figure out what they would generate is to let them do so. Fortunately, your `page` size is finite and presumably small, so this should still let you avoid whatever memory issues. That's the point of pagination, after all, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Calling `list()` would fix my problem indeed, but would create a list of all the items of the page which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I want to be able to iterate over them on the fly.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll also need some external logic to detect an empty page and break out.

Comment: Actually, hold on. This could be brutally hacked around. I'll post separately because it's a different approach entirely.

Answer (score 1):

> Calling list() would fix my problem indeed, but would create a list of all the items of the page which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I want to be able to iterate over them on the fly.

`__length_hint__` is not reliable for solving this problem; but if we allow for speculatively reading *one* item from each page as the page is generated, we can:

1. create a test for whether the page is empty, by trying to read one item
2. if it is, give back a sentinel value rather than the generator, which the outer generator processes appropriately
3. Otherwise, put the item back using a wrapper

That looks like:

```
def generator_with_prepended(iterator, value):
    yield value
    yield from iterator

def sentinelize_empty_generator(generator):
    it = iter(generator)
    try:
        first = next(it)
        return generator_with_prepended(it, first)
    except StopIteration:
        return None # which is falsey

# read_paginated_items as before

def pages_from_iterable(
    iterable: Iterable,
    page_size: int,
) -> Iterable:
    it = iter(iterable)
    while page_items_generator := sentinelize_empty_generator(read_paginated_items(it, page_size)):
        yield page_items_generator
```

Once again we need to collect results externally:

```
def test_read_by_page():
    for page in pages_from_iterable([1,2,3,4,5], 2):
        for item in page:
            print(item)
        print('---')
```

Comment: Why do you use the `iter()` function? A generator is supposed to be iterable and in `pages_from_iterable` you use a typehint. I'm not a python expert, that's why I ask if there's a reason I don't see.

Comment: On review, it probably isn't actually necessary, I was just trying to be careful re the generator state.